# Is there a way to delete user's own Facebook notifications?

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I am trying to delete the notifications in my account but not sure if it is possible, I not getting any errors with this code, but the notifications are not deleted.

```
String path = "/me/notifications/"+id ;                         
new Request(
    Session.getActiveSession(),
    path,
    null,
    HttpMethod.DELETE,
    new Request.Callback()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response)
        {
            Log.d("RESPONSE",""+response);
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

Comment: I also tried just with, id, withhout the path, and that did give me errors

Comment: I dont think so, this is happened with facebook api. Then also let me do some research and get back to you.

Comment: I have read the Facebook docs, looks like I can't delete the notifications, but maybe there is a way around it

Comment: I dont think so dear, then also let me do some research over it.